# Why should I use class methods in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I learned OOP in Python and there are 3 kinds of methods: instance methods, class methods and static methods and instance methods and static methods have their own specific usage. What about class methods? You can have access to class level variables through static methods or even instance methods. Why are there class methods?